# CSS Underline variation in IE8

Tags: css, cross-browser

I am working on a page which has searched result set. I am using a anchor tag for displaying the URL and the URL is UNDERLINED.The underline is very close to the text in IE8. Working fine in FIREFOX and IE7 but have a problem with IE8. Here is the CSS class i am using

```
.search_results_item a {
    color: #20A3E7;
    font: 13px/17px AntennaRegular,Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: is there any link for this page? Otherwise create a jsfiddle.net demo

Comment: I don't have a link to the page as it is under development. It is bit complex to to define the jsfiddle.net and firstly i need to learn how to publish it in that site. Thx for the letting me know about that site.I will play around with the site first

Comment: Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LxE7Y/

Comment: Here is the fiddle link to it http://jsfiddle.net/LxE7Y/7/

Comment: thx steve for the example. It helped me to learn new thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always use border-bottom :)

Comment: I tried using this but when you start to hover on the link to click the default underline for the anchor tag is appearing.Now i see 2 underline on hover

Answer (score 1):

Just see below the link

http://jsfiddle.net/anglimass/3ArFX/

Comment: Thx anglimass for the demo. I am able to fix the hover thing of mine. I like both answers i don't know how to mark both as valid answers in here